# An example of threefold with $K3$ fibration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am looking for an example of a smooth projective  threefold $X$ with fibration
$ \pi : X \rightarrow \mathbb P^1$ such that

1. a generic fiber $F$ of $\pi$ is a smooth $K3$ surface,
2. $K_X$ is linearly equivalent to $-2F$ and
3. $X$ is not a product of $\mathbb P^1$ and a smooth $K3$ surface.

Does such a threefold exist?

Comment: Start with a $\mathbb P^3$-bundle $p:\mathbb P(E) \to\mathbb P^1$ ($E$ being a rank $4$ vector bundle), and consider a generic section of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P(E)}(4)$ with zero locus $X$. By the accepted answer to (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559927/canonical-sheaf-projective-bundle), $K_{\mathbb P(E)} = \mathcal O_{\mathbb P(E)}(-4) \otimes \mathcal O_{\mathbb P(E)}(-2F)\otimes p^*\det E^\vee$, and applying adjunction we get $K_X = \mathcal O_X(-2F) \otimes (p^*\det E^\vee)|_X$. So as long as $E$ has degree $0$ I think you are good to go?

Comment: @TabesBridges: Let $E = \mathcal O \oplus \mathcal O \oplus \mathcal O(-1) \oplus \mathcal O(1)$. 
Is there a smooth global section of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P (E)}(4)$?

Comment: Yes, $H^0(\mathbb{P}(E)),\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(1))=\operatorname{Sym}^4(E) $ has a lot of sections. However, because of the summand $\mathscr{O}(-1)$, the corresponding threefolds are singular. The only way to get a smooth one is to take $E=\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}^4$, but then $X$ is a product of $\mathbb{P}^1$ by a K3.