# Hypersurfaces in projective bundles over $\mathbb P^1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-varieties

I am working on a suggestion of a comment [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392831/an-example-of-threefold-with-k3-fibration).
Let $E \rightarrow \mathbb P^1$ be a *non-trivial* vector bundle of rank $r$  with $\deg E =0$ and $\mathbb P(E) \rightarrow \mathbb P^1$ be its projectization.

The question is:

Is there a hypersurface  of $\mathbb P(E)$ that is linearly equivalent to   $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P(E)} (r)$ and admits a crepant resolution for some $E$?

For example, let $E = \mathcal O \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathcal O \oplus \mathcal O(-1) \oplus \mathcal O(1)$,
Is there such a hypersurface  of $\mathbb P(E)$ for some $r$?

What if $r=4$ or $5$?

If $E$ is trivial, then $\mathbb P(E) = \mathbb P^{r-1} \times \mathbb P^1$ and its hypersurface can be express by bihomogeneous polynomials.
In case that $E$ is not trivial, is there some similar concrete way to describe hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P(E)$?

Comment: If $E$ is not trivial, you can still of course trivialize over $\mathbb P^1$ and just look at two copies of $\mathbb P^{r-1}\times \mathbb A^1$. As to whether the bookkeeping is too much of a nightmare to actually do this, I am not sure.

Comment: @TabesBridges: Let $X$ be the hypersurface and $Y = X \cap (\mathbb P^{r-1} \times \mathbb A^1)$.
What is the defining polynomial of $Y$ then? Is it  a homogeneous polynomial of degree $r$ in only the variables of $\mathbb P^{r-1}$ or some mixture from those of  $\mathbb A^1$? This is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: If $x_0,...,x_{r-1}$ are homogeneous coordinates on $\mathbb P^{r-1}$ and $t$ is a coordinate on $\mathbb A^1$, the equation of $Y$ will be homogeneous in the $x_i$ but not in $t$, so it lives in $\left(k[x_0,...,x_{r-1}]_d\right)[t]$ (this notation is suggestive rather than precise as this gadget is not a ring). The tricky part is working out how changing coordinates to the other $\mathbb A^1$ affects the $x_i$, which should be nontrivial when $E$ is nontrivial.

Comment: You can take coordinates on $\mathbb{P}(E)$ as follows:
simply choose $(x_0,...,x_r,y_0,y_1)$ in $\mathbb{A}^{r+1}\setminus \{0\} \times \mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{0\}$, with the equivalence class given by
$(x_0,...,x_r,y_0,y_1)\sim (\mu x_0,\mu \lambda^{-a_1} x_1,...,\mu\lambda^{-a_r} x_r,\lambda y_0,\lambda y_1)$ where $\lambda,\mu$ are in the multiplicative group. Hypersurface are then just given by polynomials, homogeneous for this action of the $2$-dimensional torus.

Comment: Just to add a reference to Jeremy's comment: look in Reid, Chapters on algebraic surfaces, alg-geom/9602006, Chapter 2.

Comment: @user69559 - A general definition of a "hypersurface" $H(s) \subseteq X$ where $X$ is a scheme is as follows: Let $s\in H^0(L)$ be a global section of a line bundle $L$ and let $\phi_s: \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow L$ be the associated map with dual map $\phi_s^*: L^* \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$. The image $I(s):=Im(\phi_s^*) \subseteq \mathcal{O}_X$ is a coherent sheaf of ideals, and the associated closed subscheme $H(s):=V(I(s)) \subseteq X$ is a "hypersurface in $X$". On $\mathbb{P}(E^*)$ you do this construction with the tautological line bundle $\mathcal{O}(d)$.

Comment: @user69559 - I added some details in a post and if you want more information - ask for this post to be "undeleted".

Comment: @user69559 - in one of the above constructions you view $P(E^∗)$ as a "quotient" by the multiplicative group $k^∗$. If you seek a more general construction, you will find that the construction using linebundles works for any scheme $X$ and any linebundle $L\in Pic(X)$.

Comment: @user69559 - As an example: If $E:=\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}(n)$, it follows a hypersurface in $P(E^*)$ is locally defined by homogeneous degree $d$ polynomials $s_0(z_0,z_1)\in k[t][z_0,z_1]_d, s_1(w_0,w_1)\in k[1/t][w_0,w_1]$ with $s_0(w_0,t^nw_1)=s_1(w_0,w_1)$.

Comment: @user69559 - As you can yourself verify: The two polynomials $s_0,s_1$ defining the hypersurface $H(s)$ are related via the transition matrix $\phi$ defining the locally trivial sheaf $E$.